# How to check whether the keystore file has been tampered？

Tags: web3js, dapps, keystore

The format of the keystore is shown below. In the project, there is a requirement to save the keystore file from the front end to the back end. How can the back end check whether the keystore file has been tampered? For example, how to determine whether the keystore is legal after the address field is tampered with other values?

Hope you can provide me with some help, thanks!

```
{
    version: 3,
    id: '04e9bcbb-96fa-497b-94d1-14df4cd20af6',
    address: '2c7536e3605d9c16a7a3d7b1898e529396a65c23',
    crypto: {
        ciphertext: 'a1c25da3ecde4e6a24f3697251dd15d6208520efc84ad97397e906e6df24d251',
        cipherparams: { iv: '2885df2b63f7ef247d753c82fa20038a' },
        cipher: 'aes-128-ctr',
        kdf: 'scrypt',
        kdfparams: {
            dklen: 32,
            salt: '4531b3c174cc3ff32a6a7a85d6761b410db674807b2d216d022318ceee50be10',
            n: 262144,
            r: 8,
            p: 1
        },
        mac: 'b8b010fff37f9ae5559a352a185e86f9b9c1d7f7a9f1bd4e82a5dd35468fc7f6'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That file contains the private key encrypted with a password. Once the private key is decrypted the address can be derived from it.

If the decryption fails or the address is not the same then the file was tempered with.